# Define URL constant for different DIR in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, constants

So Im building a Reactjs project (still learning) and I was wondering if its possible to define a constant that can then be used in other files to determine file locations. eg:

```
IMG_ROOT = /images/
```

I could then use this whenever importing an image. eg:

```
import IMG from IMG_ROOT + filename.jpg
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not have a variables module and just import it when you need it - that way you have all vars to hand but you're not polluting the global space

Comment: sounds interesting. Care to elaborate? How would I go about this?

Comment: Sure, will add an example later on... will be a couple of hours